# Disable slider value change on tap Windows Phone 8 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a windows phone 8.1 application with some sliders for various settings.

I would like to know if it is possible to **only allow** a user **to drag** the slider to change it's value. I do not want the value of the slider to change when the user taps an area away from the slider thumb (eg jump to the tapped point).

I have tried to set IsTapEnabled to false
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.istapenabled.ASPx

I have poured through the slider xaml documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider

I still cant seem to disable 'tap change value' of the slider. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I dont think you can change that behavior, why dont you try do add a handler that detect if the current value and the changed value is more than a certain number, for example if now is 5 and selected value is 20, then roll back the value to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the slider template and set `IsHitTestVisible` to `False` for the elements with the following names:

- HorizontalTrackRect
- HorizontalDecreaseRect
- HorizontalBorder
- VerticalTrackRect
- VerticalDecreaseRect
- VerticalBorder

That should work.